# Draw lines in game scene

Tags: android

I want to do game for Android that allows draw lines. These lines should be **physic object** at the same time.

I am good at Unity3D and I tried in Unity3D. But it is not supported.

What engine should I use? Are there anybody has an idea about which engine is used in game like this?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to use then libgdx or cocos2d, but these are just for rendering. You can also make your own renderer for android.
**Important point is that you use a physics system like Box2d.** There you can define your line as a body and simulate in your box2d world.

Why box2d?
-Because, it's easy to implement on your android game project and it's a good physics engine, which has lots of documentations on the web.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet, (teşekkürler ahmet :) ) I will search these libraries

Comment: You're welcome. - Ne demek, her zaman :))